# Get directory path in HTML on localhost with python eel?

Tags: javascript, python, html, localhost, eel

I am creating a GUI application that requires the path to folder that user selects. I am using eel library of python to achieve the GUI with HTML, CSS and JS. I just want the path to the folder, I don't want the files in that folder to be uploaded.

Any Solutions ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found a work around with tkinter and may help others.

in my python I expose a tkinter function to open directories and choose a folder

```
import tkinter 
import tkinter.filedialog as filedialog

@eel.expose
def selectFolder():
    print("Here")
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.withdraw()
    directory_path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    print(directory_path)
```

in my HTML

```
<button class="items" onclick="select()">Choose folder</button>
```

in my JS I am just calling selectFolder() function from python.

```
function select(){
  eel.selectFolder();
}
```